# pfSense: Block all traffic

Tags: pfsense

I have created a pfSense firewall instance on Azure VNet and configured port forwarding so that pfSense should monitor all the traffic of VM.

I have blocked all the WAN traffic on the firewall, but when I'm trying to go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). Google page is opening.

Can anyone please help me understand how to block all WAN traffic on pfSense, or apply the default-deny policy?

For reference, I've provided the link to a screenshot of WAN rules.

https://samsolutionsin-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/yagrawal_sam-solutions_in/EcHX5ytU85pArUw6N7UvGU8BhTzysHJw1xnAmxI6IHPJMQ?e=5yG31e

Comment: fid you block in or out traffic?

Comment: I'm trying to block all outbound traffic from VNet to Internet, but allow all outbound traffic from VNet to Vnet